# URL endcoded with no content-type spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

A service is suppose to call my service as a call back to a previous request.

I set up the call back resource like the following in spring

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    @RequestMapping(value = "update/transaction",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            params = { "linkingreference", "code", "message", "reference"}
            )
    void callback(
            @RequestParam("linkingreference") String linkingreference,
            @RequestParam("code") String code,
            @RequestParam("message") String message,
            @RequestParam("reference") String reference);
```

but it keeps throwing this error below

> [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'linkingreference' for method parameter type String is not present]

I have also tried `GetMapping` same result, not working.

the blow is how the other service calls my call back resource

```
https://dev.myservice.com:9999/color/update/something?linkingreference%3DFEERB83BBAGMH3LMS4R%26code%3D00%26message%3DSuccessful%26reference%3Dab22b6535bcc4c21aabce984131733dc%26callback%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdev.myservice.com%3A8443%2Fseerbit%2Fupdate%2Ftransaction
```

but checking the browser from inspect, it does not pass a `content-type` and I think that might be the issue but how do I read a url-encoded URL without the `content-type` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Are you encoding the `=`? Never seen that before.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yea crazy. I am not the one encoding it, it's how my url is being called